# pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily not working suddenly

Tags: pandas, yahoo-finance, datareader

One week ago, I ran the following code and did not get an error.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.yahoo.daily as yd
df1 = yd.YahooDailyReader("SPY", interval='d', start=dt.date(2022,7,1),end=dt.date.today()).read()
```

However, when I tried the same code today, I got the following error message:

[image: error message]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The error occurred because library did not receive expected result from Yahoo API. Maybe Yahoo changed its API or its service is throwing some errors.

Answer (score 1):

It seems yahoo finance has changed it API or the service is down.

You can use Tiingo API instead (you need to make an account to get an API token)

```
import pandas_datareader as web
r = web.get_data_tiingo("SPY", api_key=ENV('NEWS_TOKEN'))
```

see: [Remote Data Access#Tiingo](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#tiingo)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, yfinance is still working

import yfinance as yf

from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

my_data = yf.download('TSLA', start='2021-12-17', end='2022-12-17', progress=False)